# Как считать значение из Edit

Tags: delphi

В поле `Edit` можно вводить различные числа, что бы при вводе числа `"1"` у меня нажималась кнопка `Button1`.

Я пробовал сам с помощью этого кода:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;  


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    If Edit1.Text:='1' then
   Button1.Click;
end;
```

Дело в том, что моё значение в поле `Edit` сохраняется в `ini` Файл при закрытии, я хотел бы, что бы при открытии программы, в случае если последнее сохранённое число было `"1"`, то кнопка нажималась. 
Версия `delphi` не известна.

Comment: собственно, алгоритм вы уже расписали: считываем значение из ini и если оно равно 1 то нажимаем кнопку. С чем у вас возникли проблемы? В приведенном вами коде нет первого пункта алгоритма - считывание значения из ini.

Comment: версию delphi вы можете найти в about. Вообще когда изменение одного элемента вызывает например кликл по кнопке, это плохо. А хорошо, это когда нужный код вынесен в отдельную процедуру и вызывается из всех необходимых мест. у Edit есть множество собтытий, в т.ч. Сhange или KeyPress и т.п. смотрите в их сорону. А что касается открытия программы и выполнения, это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте прописать свой код в событие OnShow, дело в том что когда происходит событие формы OnCreate кнопки еще не существует и нажать ее невозможно. В OnShow все должно сработать.

Кроме того в коде ошибка, должно быть примерно так

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
    If Edit1.Text='1' then
   Button1.Click;
end;
```

Comment: @Kromster Хорошо. "когда происходит событие формы OnCreate кнопки еще не существует" - это утверждение ложно.

Comment: @Igor здорово, спасибо! *не флагал )